# Need help creating a folder tree component in React with the given json structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, recursion, array.prototype.map

I am trying to build a **folder tree component** where initially the component will only render the names of items at the first layer (item1, item2, item3), then when an specific item is clicked, it would show me everything listed on the next layer for that item(i.e. click on **item1** would show **item1.1** and **item1.2,** click on **item1.1** will show **item1.1.1**). This should be done in a loop until it reaches the final layer with the just the attributes (attr1, attr2, attr3).

**Note: I have simplified the item names for demo purposes, but in reality they don't follow a specific pattern/naming system.**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';


const Testing = () => {
    const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
    
    const data = {
        "item1": {
            "item1.1": {
                "item1.1.1": {
                    "item1.1.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    }
                }
            },
            "item1.2": {
                "item1.2.1": {
                    "item1.2.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "item2": {
            "item2.1": {
                "item2.1.1": {
                    "item2.1.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    }
                },
                "item2.1.2": {
                    "item2.1.2.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    },
                    "item2.1.2.2": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "item3": {
            "item3.1": {
                "item3.1.1": {
                    "item3.1.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    }
                },
                "item3.1.2": {
                    "attr1": [],
                    "attr2": "",
                    "attr3": []
                }
            }
        }

    }

    function parse(data) {
        if (typeof data === 'object') {
            return (
                <li>
                    <ul>
                        {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => (
                            <>
                                <li>
                                    {key}: {typeof value === 'string' ? value : ''}
                                </li>
                                {parse(value)}
                            </>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </li>
            );
        }
        if (typeof data === 'object') return (<li>{data}</li>);
        return null;
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="App">
                {Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
                    return (
                        <ul>
                            <span onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}>{key}</span>
                            <br />
                            <div style={{ display: expand ? "block" : "none", paddingLeft: 15 }}>
                                {parse(value)}
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Testing;
```

Here a picture of the output I'm getting right now with the code above: [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDZLH.png); it shows item1, item2, item3 in a list; but when I click on any of them, it will just render everything else, I'm trying to find a way so that it behaves similar to a file directory tree as shown in the demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/folder-structuring-t6oj4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that in the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/folder-structuring-t6oj4) they use a recursive component that has its own `expand` state managed with a hook. So every `Folder` will have a distinct value for the `expand` variable that is inside their scope.

On the other hand, your `Testing` component manages a single `expand` state and the whole rendering uses that state for every "folder" that's the reason why when you click a folder it toggles the state for the whole component, what you should do is refactor your component so that it also manages its own state in each Folder, something like this which is in the demo:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Folder ({ name, file }) {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  if (typeof file !== "object") return <span>{file}</span>;
  return (
    <div>
      <span onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}>{name}</span>
      <br/>
      <div style={{ display: expand ? "block" : "none", paddingLeft: 15 }} >
        {
          Object.entries(file).map(([key, value]) => (
            <Folder key={key} name={key} file={value} />
          ))
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then just call it in your component:

```
import React from 'react';


const Testing = () => {
    const data = {
        "item1": {
            "item1.1": {
                "item1.1.1": {
                    "item1.1.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    }
                }
            },
            "item1.2": {
                "item1.2.1": {
                    "item1.2.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "item2": {
            "item2.1": {
                "item2.1.1": {
                    "item2.1.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    }
                },
                "item2.1.2": {
                    "item2.1.2.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    },
                    "item2.1.2.2": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "item3": {
            "item3.1": {
                "item3.1.1": {
                    "item3.1.1.1": {
                        "attr1": [],
                        "attr2": "",
                        "attr3": []
                    }
                },
                "item3.1.2": {
                    "attr1": [],
                    "attr2": "",
                    "attr3": []
                }
            }
        }

    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="App">
                <Folder name="/root" file={data} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Edit: Refactored the code so that only the selected folder expands on click

Comment: Thanks for the provided solution. I did notice one problem with your method however, whenever I click on a parent folder, it will not only expand that item, but all other folders on the same layer as well. (i.e clicking on item1 will expand item1, item2 and item3, instead of just item1). is there a way to refactor this to control the expand state for individual folders?

Comment: Just updated the answer so that only the clicked folder expands